# Access function by dot path without disconnecting `this` (maintain `this` on destructure)

Tags: javascript

I have a function that executes functions in a scope. Super simplified case:

```
function exec(method_name, ...args) {
   scope[method_name](...args);
}
```

Now i have a need to execute a method in an object in the scope. The object is named `foo` and I need to execute `foo.bar()`.

When I do this:

```
class FooBar {
   constructor() {
       this.msg = 'hiii';
       this.bar = this.bar.bind(this);
   }
   bar()
      alert(this.msg);
   }
}

var foo = new FooBar;

const deepAccessUsingString = (obj, dotpath) => dotpath.split('.').reduce((nested, key) => nested[key], obj);

function exec(mdotpath, ...args) {
    deepAccessUsingString(scope, mdotpath)(...args);
}

exec('foo.bar');
```

I am getting disconnected from `this`. If I do `foo.bar()` it works perfectly.

Is there any way other then hard coding in different cases for number of arguments like this below:

```
let md = mdotpath.split('.');
switch(md.length) {
   case 1: return scope[md[0]];
   case 2: return scope[md[0]][md[1]]();
   case 3: return scope[md[0]][md[1]][md[2]]();
   default: throw new Error('not yet supported, you need to hard code in for length of ' + md.length)
}
```

Comment: It's not that it is "disconnected", since it's not "connected" in the very first place. It is resolved in runtime during a call. Btw, your code "works" if you specify the correct `scope` object.

Comment: Your `class` syntax is invalid and arrow functions don't have a `this` for which you can specify a value. I don't know how `foo.bar()` could ever work as you say.

Comment: Oh @squint I used babel to transpile it, I'm so used to that. I'll edit it to show you what babel is doing.

Comment: https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Comment: @squint `arrow functions don't have a this` there is a little slight of hands there, they don't have their own this they rather inherit the one in the enclosing scope. @Noitidart how ever i have found that babel sometimes screws the binding. in your case you might want bind the function before executing it either using `bind`, `apply` or `call` it all depends on how you want to pass arguments if any.

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon: Full quote: *"arrow functions don't have a `this` for which you can specify a value"*. And I'd be cautious about using the word *"inherit"* here. I get what you mean, but it may add confusion.

Comment: @Noitidart: No matter what, you're going to need the object that is meant to be the *thisArg* because of the dynamic nature of `this` in JS. In order to keep your `deepAccessUsingString` function generic, I'd probably change it to use `.map()` and return the full depth of the object traversal, so you can use those objects as needed. In this case, the last two will be the object and function you want, so you can use `.apply()` to set the `this` value when invoking the function. https://jsfiddle.net/xrjq8s6m/

Comment: Thanks @squint I really appreciate that idea input